# how to get a perspecitve look to an orthogonal tilemap

Tags: libgdx, transform, perspective, orthogonal, tiled

I am currentliy using an orthogonal map, not an isometric. But I would like to get an perspective look. the first picuture shows, what I currently have, the second shows my goal.

Isn't it possible to do it with a transform matrix somehow? I did only manage to scale the whole image..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`MapRenderer.setView(...)`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/maps/MapRenderer.html#setView-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4-float-float-float-float-) to achieve that.

Create a `PerspectiveCamera` and set it up to have the perspective that you've shown in your second picture. Note that the tiled map will be rendered to the X/Y-plane and you need to set your camera's position and look-at vectors accordingly.

When you are done with that, use `MapRenderer.setView(...)` with the `camera.combined` matrix.

Comment: Hi I'm trying to do this too so I can use 3D models on top of the tiledMap. Any tips on how to convert the xy screen coords to the tiledmap using the perspective camera? (can't use unproject)

Answer (score -1):

Be careful; as [said by noone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24722965/444991), you will still have 2D pixel: no 3D geometry: sprited will not be hidden behind wall.

If you want to achieve some simple fake perspective, you will have to code it yourself.
The idea is to use use 2 different layers in the map, one for all the basic stuff (floor, walls, objects) and one for all elements that should hide all things drawn before – the “perspective”.

Then with some code, render the floor tiles, sprites and then the perspective layer to hide objects.

I have written a blog entry to achieved this with libgdx, which you can find [here](http://gameover.co.in/2014/04/perspective-with-2d-files-map-in-libgdx/).