# Combine Orthographic and perspective camera libgdx

Tags: libgdx, perspectivecamera, orthographic

How can I properly mix them together? I'm showing tiled map in ortho. camera and now I want the buildings to reach higher (GTA1 style). I'm not sure how to synchronize, I guess better will be, to just use perspective camera only, but how can I then use TiledMapRenderer?

Comment: You can use a PerspectiveCamera and do the math to position it correctly. Do you want to look straight down at the floor, or angled down? I wrote a Viewport class that can angle a perspective camera down and automatically position it to show a certain amount of vertical area on the XY plane, similar to how you can carefully control the vertical viewing area of an ortho camera. Does it need to rotate left and right, or do you always point north?

Comment: I guess GTA1 style is just a perspective projection with the camera moving parallely to the ground in an aereal position center in the character.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the map renderer does not support perspective camera. I will need to create the map different way then usin Tiled editor. It must be full 3D map. Can somebody recommend some easy to use Tiled like 3D map creator?

Comment: Same problem [here](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5370&p=25771)

Comment: I guess this one can help [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24722965/2944265](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24722965/2944265)